# Javascript Regex to split line of log with key value pairs

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a log like

```
t=2016-08-03T18:47:26+0000 lvl=dbug msg="Event Received" Service=SomeService
```

and I want to turn it into a javascript object like

```
{
  t: 2016-08-03T18:47:26+0000,
  lvl: dbug
  msg: "Event Received"
  Service: SomeService
}
```

But I am having trouble coming up with a regex that will detect the string "Event Received" in the log line. 
I want to split the log line by space but because of the string it is much more difficult.

I am trying to come up with a regex that will detect the fields and parameters so that I can isolate them and split with the equal sign.

Comment: If you are the producer of the log lines, you could make your job much easier by using an "invisible" character. For instance, change the field separator from `" "` to something like `" \x1F"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a regex without any lookahead:

```
var re = /(\w+)=(?:"([^"]*)"|(\S*))/g;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD3nZ2/1)

The point is that the first group (`(\w+)`) captures the attribute name and the 2nd and 3rd are placed into a non-capturing "container" as alternative branches. Their values can be checked and then either one will be used to fill out the object.

**Pattern details**:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1 (attribute name) matching 1+ word chars (from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` ranges)
- `=` - an equal sign
- `(?:"([^"]*)"|(\S*))` - a non-capturing "container" group matching either of the two alternatives:

  - `"([^"]*)"` - a quote, then Group 2 capturing 0+ chars other than `"`, and a quote
  - `|` - or
  - `(\S*)` - Group 3 capturing 0+ non-whitespace symbols.

```js
var rx = /(\w+)=(?:"([^"]*)"|(\S*))/g;
var s = "t=2016-08-03T18:47:26+0000 lvl=dbug msg=\"Event Received\" Service=SomeService";
var obj = {};

while((m=rx.exec(s))!==null) {
 if (m[2]) {
     obj[m[1]] = m[2];
 } else {
     obj[m[1]] = m[3];
 }
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to capture various `name=value` pairs:

```
/(\w+)=(.*?)(?= \w+=|$)/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vV7jQ4/1)

**Code:**

```js
var re = /(\w+)=(.*?)(?= \w+=|$)/gm;
var str = 't=2016-08-03T18:47:26+0000 lvl=dbug msg="Event Received" Service=SomeService';
var m;
var result = {};

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   if (m.index === re.lastIndex)
      re.lastIndex++;
   result[m[1]] = m[2];
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This answer won't work in case of [`msg="Event Recieved="`](https://regex101.com/r/vV7jQ4/2).

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below

```
var x = 't=2016-08-03T18:47:26+0000 lvl=dbug msg="Event Received" Service=SomeService';

var y = x.replace(/=/g,':').split(' ');

var z = '{'+ y+'}';



console.log(z);
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/oLPRAy

Comment: If I take the question to the letter OP wants an object rather than a String though. If that is indeed the case, you could add a `JSON.parse` call at the end.

Comment: JSON.parse will fail with unexpected token, JSON.parse of JSON stringify will make it object  ... Thanks @Aaron :)

Comment: JSON.parse fails because your String still contains equal signs rather than `:`, I didn't notice that at first. Stringifying it then parsing it again will just yield the String again.

Comment: Nice, but you should now remove the extra `JSON.stringify` in order to get an object rather than a string. Edit : meh, that still won't work because the date and "dbug" aren't quoted. I'm not sure it's worth the effort of modifying your answer to handle that since OP found a solution, maybe you should remove the whole JSON.parse/stringify and keep it as a string.

Comment: yes @Aaron ... OP has found solution and leaving output as string

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
/^t=([^ ]+) lvl=([^ ]+) msg=(.*?[a-z]") Service=(.*)$/gm
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kS2rJ5/2)

Comment: "Use this pattern" - why? Some explanation would be handy for OP and future readers.